# how to validate jwt token in Laravel thorugh postman

Tags: laravel, postman, jwt

I am a beginner in Laravel. I have successfully generated a jwt token, and I want to send this token to another api which will authenticate it and sends the response of dishes. But my code is not validating the token, and gives me the response even if I send the wrong token.

How can I solve this?

[image: postman api call]

Code:

```
class DishController extends Controller
{    
    public function self()
    {
        try{
        $user = Auth->user();
        $dishes =  Dish::all();
    }
    catch(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\UserNotDefinedException $e){
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }

    return response()->json($dishes);    
  }

 }
```

Api route

```
Route::get('/dish/self',[
'as' =>'login.login',
'uses' => 'DishController@self'
]);
```

Comment: Tymon\JWTAuth is a dumb package. I do not consider it JWT. It's basically abusing the JWT concept by just giving an encrypted cookie with a user ID. the ID is then resolved to a user object in the backend. In other words, you can just as well use a session.

Comment: i don't understand dumb package. please can you explain more

Comment: Sadly most people dont know the specifics about JWT. I think that package falsely advertises as a JSON Web Token implementation. Let me just ask you the question: why are you using JWT?

Answer (score 0):

in your route, you should gives a middleware (**apiJwt**), see  below the code:

```
Route::middleware("apiJwt")->get('/dish/self',[
    'as' =>'login.login',
    'uses' => 'DishController@self'
 ])
```

something like this

remember, you should install some packages like the **tymon/jwt-auth**